# Howto: Programmatically add AppBarCommand to Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, winjs, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Store app that uses the following code to add [AppBarCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700497.aspx) and that code does not work on Windows Phone 8.1

```
function showBars() {
    var appBar = document.createElement('div');
    var command = document.createElement('button');

    new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBar);
    new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(command, { label: 'Hello', icon: 'add' });

    appBar.appendChild(command);

    document.body.appendChild(appBar);
}
```

I also created the simplest [Universal app](http://1drv.ms/1lHU4Dl) which show how that code works fine on the Windows Store app while it does not show any command on the Windows Phone app.

Is it even possible to add commands programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending the `command` element to the `appBar` element, you'll have to add the command control to the appbar control. This can be done by setting the `commands` property of the appbar.

Like this:

```
function showBars() {
    var appBar = document.createElement('div');
    var command = document.createElement('button');

    var commandObject = new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(command, { label: 'Hello', icon: 'add' });

    new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBar, { commands: [commandObject] });

    document.body.appendChild(appBar);
}
```

Comment: great, that did the trick, but why isn't my code working on Win Phone while it does on Windows?

Comment: I wonder why the MSDN does not contain such vital information.